# sort an object in descending order of one field

Tags: java, sorting, guava, comparable, multimap

I have a multimap which will contain bunch of keys and values in it.

```
private final Multimap<String, Process> processById = TreeMultimap.create();
```

Now for same key I can have bunch of `Process` so that's why I am using multimap here. Now I need to sort `Process` object in descending order of `endTime` in it. For each key in the map when I iterate the `List<Process>`, it should print process object in descending order of `endTime`. So I implemented `Comparable` interface here.

```
public final class Process implements Comparable<Process> {
  private final String clientId;
  private final long endTime;
  // .. more fields

  //... constructor, getters, toString methods

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Process o) {
    // is this logic right here?
    return Long.compare(this.endTime, o.endTime) * (-1);
  }
}
```

My question is - Is this the right way to do or my logic is wrong here?

```
Process process = getProcess(task);
String id = task.getId();
// populate multimap here
processById.put(id, process);
```

Comment: Your code seem to work. Your logic seem OK too. Is there any problem with your code?

Comment: Multiplying by `-1` is the only option I have here to get this sorted in descending order or is there any other way?

Comment: Multiplying by `-1` is equal to `Long.compare(o.endTime, this.endTime)`, so in your case I think it right. TreeMap does not let you put a `null` as a key. So your `compareTo` method is right too. If you may want to work with nullable container, you should consider to check null first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking us to validate your expectation without having actually tried it is off-topic.  You are expected to actually TRY your solution and ask questions when it doesn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to multiply by -1, better to just reverse the fields.